# How to make FlyWay to work with several databases?

Tags: java, sql, flyway

I have FlyWay config class, which starts on application startup and executes sql migrations. Parameters for database connection are taken from environment and there I plan to put a flag which will help Flyway to determine of its production, or test env. So for test server with test env I need Flyway to setup 2 databases - one like on prod and one for integration tests.

Here is my Flyway config:

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class FlyWayConfig {
    private static final Map<String, String> ENV_VARIABLES = System.getenv();
    private static final String ENV_TEST = "env_test";
    private static final String MIGRATIONS_PATH = "db/migration";
    private static final String MIGRATIONS_TEST_PATH = "filesystem:db/migration-test";

    @Resource
    private static MariaDbDataSource dataSource;

    @Resource
    private static MariaDbDataSource dataSourceForTests;

    static {
        dataSource = new MariaDbDataSource();
        dataSourceForTests = new MariaDbDataSource();
        setupDataSource();
    }

    private static void setupDataSource() {
        try {
            dataSource.setUrl(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_URL.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setDatabaseName(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_SCHEMA.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setUser(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_USER.getParameter()));
            dataSource.setPassword(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_USER_PASSWORD.getParameter()));

            if (Objects.nonNull(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.ENV_TEST.getParameter()))
                    && ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.ENV_TEST.getParameter()).equals(ENV_TEST)) {
                dataSourceForTests.setUrl(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_TEST_URL.getParameter()));
                dataSourceForTests.setDatabaseName(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_TEST_SCHEMA.getParameter()));
                dataSourceForTests.setUser(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_USER.getParameter()));
                dataSourceForTests.setPassword(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_USER_PASSWORD.getParameter()));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("FlyWay: Database connection failed. Possible problem with configuration");
        }
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void onStartup() {
        Flyway flyway = configureFlyWay();
        flyway.migrate();

        if (Objects.nonNull(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.ENV_TEST.getParameter()))
                && ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.ENV_TEST.getParameter()).equals(ENV_TEST)) {
            Flyway flywayTest = configureFlyWayForTestingDatabase();
            flywayTest.migrate();

            log.info("FlyWay: Successfully migrated to test database version: {}", flyway.info().current().getVersion());
        }

        log.info("FlyWay: Successfully migrated to database version: {}", flyway.info().current().getVersion());
    }

    private Flyway configureFlyWay() {
        return Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .schemas(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_SCHEMA.getParameter()))
                .locations(MIGRATIONS_PATH)
                .load();
    }

    private Flyway configureFlyWayForTestingDatabase() {

        return Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(dataSourceForTests)
                .schemas(ENV_VARIABLES.get(FlyWayParameters.DB_TEST_SCHEMA.getParameter()))
                .locations(MIGRATIONS_TEST_PATH)
                .load();
    }
}
```

Almost everything is working except test database path - I put migration scripts for tests in test resources folder and tried to set different paths for `MIGRATIONS_TEST_PATH`(tried also `'claspath::db/migration-test'`), but unfortunately on start FLyway does not find my scripts and simply creates empty version table. In logs I have:

```
09:32:13,367 INFO  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.001s)
09:32:13,367 WARN  [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 13) No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?
```

How can I point Flyway necessary directory to find those migrations?